# VS Code won't let me save a go test file

Tags: visual-studio-code, terraform, terratest

I'm trying to save a file with VS Code.

UPDATE

I guess I should have asked how, independent of what the code is, you can force VS Code to Save a file when you hit Ctrl S rather than editing your file and then saving it?

====

VS Code is reporting a problem here:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
)
```

and outputting:

```
could not import github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform (cannot find package "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform" in any of 
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform (from $GOROOT)
/home/snowcrash/go/src/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform
```

When I Ctrl S, VS Code removes the line.

It may be a problem but I'd like to be able to save and test it.

I guess:

1. how do I save the file?

(Note I can do it with `vim` but would like to know how you do it with VS Code)

Comment: Have you read about how to import dependencies in Go? You might find golang.org/doc/code#ImportingRemote useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

99.9% of the time you're fine with VS Code.

For that 0.1% of the time when you're having problems saving a file using VS Code and don't have time to waste a few hours on working out why, just use vim.